# Homeomorphic tori

Tags: general-topology

I want to Show that the torus $T=\mathbb{S^1}\times\mathbb{S^1}$ is homeomorphic to the circle $\{(x,z)|(x-2)^2+z^2=1\}$ rotated around the $(x,z)$-plane. I feel confident that I can show that the required map are continous but can someone give me the map please? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Rather than rotated around the $(x,z)$-plane, perhaps you mean revolved around the $y$-axis?

Answer (score 0):

If we want to show that a product $\mathbb{S^1}\times\mathbb{S^1}$ of circles is homeomorphic to a rotated circle $C$, then it is natural to define a homeomorphism $h$ by means of angles. For instance, if $p=(e^{\alpha i}, e^{\beta i})\in \mathbb{S^1}\times\mathbb{S^1}$ for some angles $\alpha,\beta$ then as $h(p)$ we may define a point on the circle $C$ lying from an angle $\alpha$ from it fixed radius and then rotated by an  angle $\beta$.